# how to know what caused visibilitychange

Tags: javascript

I am using `visibilitychange` event of the browser. The website is for mobiles. So I test it from my mobile.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', (e) => {
    console.log("visibility changed", e);
})
```

This could be caused by many different things.

- switching apps back and forth
- force-closing app
- when the screen turns off

Is there any way to detect what behaviour caused `visibilitychange` listener to get called? I tried `e.target` and `e.srcElement`, but in all cases, they seem to be the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't think so - you'd have to look into the mobile side of things a bit more.

Comment: any idea you can think of ? I want to know if screen turned off or user switched the apps .

Comment: You don't get to know these things, this are privacy stuff that can't be read by websites. It's also not relevant to your site at all, if the user navigates away it's his decision.

Comment: If I use `fullscreen api` , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API , calling fullscreen also calls `visibilitychange` event. Would there be a way to detect this and not call my `visibilitychange` event, if fullscreen happened?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: *you can't*

As stated in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) for the `visibilitychange` event:

> The visibilitychange event is fired at the document when the content of its tab have become visible or have been hidden.

You only have two value possible, `visible` or `hidden`. That's all the website can know. You are asking a web browser to have acute knowledge of what the user is doing on his operating system *(did he locked his computer? did he switch to a new app? did he kill the web browser?)* which is privacy wise, not very useful nor safe.

**However** if you absolutely need these features and can afford to make the user install your app, you could use something like [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).